# Can you transfer Qantas Frequent Flyer Points to other (non-family) members?

Tags: loyalty-programs, qantas

Someone's offered to sell me QFF points. I realise you can transfer between family members, but I was wondering whether this is in line with their terms and conditions for non-family members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's against the [T&Cs](http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/program/terms#jump10) on two points.  First, transfers are allowed only to family members, and second, they can only be transferred as gifts, not in exchange for money:

> 11.3 Members must not require or receive any consideration (in the form of a payment or otherwise) for any transfer to an Eligible Family
>   Member.

While you're unlikely to get busted for casual buddy transfers, if the person offering to sell you points does this on a habitual basis, they may well be caught by an automated sweep looking for (say) people "donating" to over 10 "family members".  And if they are caught, as their customer you also stand to lose your points or your membership:

> 8.1 If a Member has committed a material breach of any of the Terms and Conditions or has failed to pay any money due under Qantas
>   Frequent Flyer or The Qantas Club by the due date, whether
>   intentionally or otherwise, then Qantas may do any one or more of the
>   following: (a) suspend or terminate the Member's Membership and/or the
>   right of the Member to use the Card; (b) reverse or cancel the
>   Member's Points or any part thereof; or (c) cancel or refuse to honour
>   any Awards (including ticketed Award Flights), Benefits or both, that
>   have been redeemed by or provided to the Member.

Answer (score 4):

You can (officially) only transfer points to a [family member](http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/program/terms#jump10).  Family members are [defined on their website](http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/program/terms#jump1) as :

```
Husband/Wife
Parent/Step-parent
Domestic Partner/De Facto
Child, including foster & step-child
Brother/Sister
Half Brother/Sister
Grandparent
Grandchild
Son/Daughter-in-law
Brother/Sister-in-law
Father/Mother-in-law
Uncle/Aunt
Nephew/Niece
First cousin
```